# Correct use of preposition

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> He wrote the car ______ in an accident.

a) down b) up c) by d) off e) out

I think it's "out" but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: My Google-fu skills led me to **[this article](http://driving.ca/auto-news/news/what-happens-when-your-car-is-written-off)**, indicating "wrote off" as a plausible candidate.

Answer (score 1):

To **write off** something is to acknowledge a significant loss in value which happens due to some action.

Your sentence :

> He **wrote** the car **off** in an accident.

means the car was in a serious accident and possibly became **unuseable**, therefore its value significantly decreased, maybe to only **salvage value**.

> Because the car was **totalled** in the accident, he **wrote** it **off**.

Because of the **in**, your sentence can have the awkward interpretation of :

> While in the middle of having his accident, he devalued his car.

One does not usually **write off** *something* **during** an event, but only **after** the event has taken place.

Answer (score 1):

"Off" is correct. 
It is an idiom. 
One can say afterwards that the "car was a total write-off" implying it can't be salvaged.